# Angular: format for saving and loading multiple select data

Tags: angularjs

I have a multiselect field in an angular form:

```
<div crm-ui-field="{name: 'subform.committees', title: ts('Secondary Committee')}">
  <div ng-controller="CommitteeCtrl">
    <select
      multiple="multiple"
      crm-ui-id="subform.committees"
      name="secondary_committee"
      crm-ui-select="{dropdownAutoWidth : true, allowClear: false, placeholder: ts('Choose Committee')}"
      ng-model="mailing.secondary_committee"
      ng-options="comm as comm.label for comm in comms track by comm.value"
    >
      <option />
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm running into problems trying to figure out how to store the data and retrieve it so that the angular form loads the values properly. How does angular expect to see the data?

Comment: How about this [one](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/select)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For MultiSelect ng-model is an `Array`, 
while Sending to Back-end you need to make [] as string, then it will fit into one column in DB:

```
var secondaryCommitteeStr = $scope.mailing.secondary_committee.join(',');
```

so while retrieving, you need to set your model data as selected entity's array, then angular will automatically populate selection entity's `$scope.mailing.secondary_committee`.

```
$scope.mailing.secondary_committee = data.split(',');// service data
```

Comment: yes, on the retrieval step I wasn't converting back to an array, which was causing the issue.